# get_multi / set_multi atomic?

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency, memcached, atomic

In the [official FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ) of Memcached i read:

"All individual commands sent to memcached are absolutely atomic."

However this is still unclear to me when it comes to `get_multi` and `set_multi`. I'd like to know whether `get_multi` and `set_multi` are  atomic in the following sense:

- All writes performed by set_multi will be performed together atomically.
- All reads performed by get_multi will be performed together atomically.

For example these situations should be impossible:

1)

- Initially contents of the cache is `{'a': 0, 'b': 0}`
- machine A calls `set_multi({'a': 1, 'b': 1})`
- machine B calls `get_multi(['a', 'b'])` and receives `{'a': 1, 'b': 0}`

2)

- Initially contents of the cache is `{'a': 0, 'b': 0}`
- machine A calls `set({'a': 1})
- machine A calls `set({'b': 2})
- machine B calls `get_multi(['a', 'b'])` and receives `{'a': 0, 'b': 2}`

This question is just so important for my design, that I thought I'd better ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As I read this section](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Batch_your_requests_with_get_multi), `get_multi` issues multiple requests that run in parallel, the idea being that for large requests, `get_multi` allows the total amount of time to get all results to be reduced. I don't see any guarantee or mention that the independent requests, done together, are collectively atomic. The same rule likely applies to `set_multi` (i.e. the individual requests are atomic, but the collection of them is not).

There also appears to be no mention of transactions.

Comment: I think you're right. It seems the protocol doesn't even support it. I incorrectly assumed that library routines are in 1-1 correspondence with the actual cache operations.

Comment: Correct.  get_multi is an optimization.  In the binary protocol, you can make a similar optimization by sending multiple objects together, but they're all effectively individual requests.